# ReactNative: How to send image cropped by ImageEditor.cropImage, using FormData

Tags: javascript, ajax, react-native

I wanna crop image using `ImageEditor.cropImage`, and send it to server using FormData.

When I crop image using `ImageEditor.cropImage`, I get `ImageStore` tag like `rn_image_store://0`, not the absolute URI of the image.

How can I get the image uri from ImageStore, and send it?

I don't wanna use BASE64 encoding to get image from ImageStore.
https://facebook.github.io/react-native/docs/imagestore.html

Comment: Facing the same issue. Do you have any solution for this?

Comment: Not yet :( I guess RN removed methods to get a real path in the past. Solution is using Base64 format. Get data by `ImageStore.getBase64ForTag()` and save it in some path using https://github.com/joltup/rn-fetch-blob .

Answer (score 0):

Resolved by specifying the ImageStore tag as image URI.

Comment: I am facing the same problem, can you give more context about your solution, please?